# Android Monkey not writing to scriptlog.txt (permission denied)

Tags: android, android-monkey

Just started trying to use the android monkey tool, and it's working fine, except that for during the run it prints thousands of lines of the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/scriptlog.txt (Permission Denied)
```

Why would it fail to write to the /mnt/sdcard? Is there an option to write to a different directory on the host machine, or to disable the log entirely?

If it matters, my device is not rooted.

I also tried running the command in a windows administrator shell, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you given File Permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: My app has `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for other reasons, but I didn't think this would matter. The app can't even read/write the external storage because it's currently mounted on the pc host running monkey. I guess it would be `adb` or the monkey tool trying to write the log?